Data table not working in jquery ajax response
I want to show data in a pop-up using data-tables. I am building pop-up on click event and when I get success response from AJAX Request then I want to show that data in data-tables format(pagination, search, export).
Here is my AJAX success Code -
success: (response) => {
                if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#dataTable2')) {
                    $('#dataTable2').DataTable().destroy();
                }
                $('#dataTable2 tbody').empty();

                $('#dataTable2').DataTable({
                    dom: '<"datatable-header"lBfrtip>',
                    lengthMenu: [
                        [10, 25, 50, -1],
                        [10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    buttons: [{
                        extend: 'collection',
                        text: 'Export',
                        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'print']
                    }],
                    initComplete: function() {
                        $('.dt-buttons').css({
                            'position': 'absolute',
                            'top': '15px',
                            'right': '100px'
                        });
                    }
                });

                document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display = 'block';
                $('#dataTable2').addClass('js-dataTable');
                $('#dataTable2').html(response);
                $('#lightbox').show();

            }


HTML code -
<div id="lightbox">
            <div id="lightbox-content">
                <span class="close" onclick="closeLightbox()">&times;</span>
                <div class="row mt-4">
                    <div class="col-md-12 table-container">
                        <table id="dataTable2" class="table table-hover table-striped no-footer" aria-describedby="dataTable_info">
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


Error -
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'aDataSort')
    at _fnSortFlatten (backend.js?id=45e6969aba26e99cc456499f7b307f41:193000:35)
    at _fnSortingClasses (backend.js?id=45e6969aba26e99cc456499f7b307f41:193338:13)
    at loadedInit (backend.js?id=45e6969aba26e99cc456499f7b307f41:188170:4)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (backend.js?id=45e6969aba26e99cc456499f7b307f41:188269:4)
    at Function.each (backend.js?id=45e6969aba26e99cc456499f7b307f41:127655:19)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (backend.js?id=45e6969aba26e99cc456499f7b307f41:127477:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (backend.js?id=45e6969aba26e99cc456499f7b307f41:187821:7)
    at $.fn.DataTable (backend.js?id=45e6969aba26e99cc456499f7b307f41:202685:17)


